# CURL 404 Error. on ajax function

Tags: php, curl

PHP:

```
$url = "http://www.smsidea.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=9427362750&pass=***&senderid=SMSWEB&to=".$data['mobile']."&msg=".$data['message']."";
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
); 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://www.kakaproperty.com/Property/send_message",
          data: data,
          success: function(response){
            alert(response);
          }
        })
```

output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I am using CRUL with ajax function. but it returning error 400 Bad Request anyone can please help me how can I resolve this error.

Comment: The problem is not in Curl request per se, it's in parameters you send. For example, you're sending to smsidea.co.in wrong or insufficient data. Have you tried that URL manually, does it work?

Comment: Yes it working but not working in curl

Comment: Try removing headers. First, try removing all of them, then add them one by one. Are you sure you do need all 10 of them? I doubt it, they look like copy pasted from somewhere